# What is the maximum RAM capacity for an HP Pavilion G7-1255sa?

Tags: windows-7, memory, hp-pavilion

I'm thinking about buying an HP Pavilion G7-1255sa and already considering upgrades.

The model I'm looking at ships with 4GB of RAM as 1x4GB.
Obvious choice is to throw another 4GB into the one spare slot, right?

But the spec says max supported RAM 6GB. **Why?**

Elsewhere on the HP site it says that anything running Windows 7 64bit supports up to 16GB, and Intel says the i52430 supports up to 16GB. So what's with the 6GB?

Is it deliberately restricted? Is it a typo that's been copied onto various sites? Or am I just flaunting my ignorance of the way these things work? Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the processor and Windows may be able to handle that much RAM, the motherboard may be limited to that much. If you intend to purchase more than the indicated 6GB, you will want to shop elsewhere for a machine that will allow more RAM of your choice.

Comment: Hmmm - ok, thanks for that - looks like I'll be getting something different then!

Answer (score 1):

[HP specs say 6gb](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03018895&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en), it can be a motherboard chipset limitation, number of memory slots restriction or a bios level limitation, regardless there is nothing much you can do about it.

.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a heads up I didn't check how old this thread is but I have the exact laptop and have upgraded to 8Gb RAM and it is working fine and shows up in both task manager and computer propterties and has also imrpoved gaming experience.

Comment: i suppose 2x4GB sticks?